# How to Introduce a space before the footer

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, haml

Top Navigation Bar with spacing (gray)

[image]

No spacing right before the footer:

[image]

My Layout File ("navigation_top" is the black nav bar at the top)

```
%body
  = render "navigation_top"
  .main-content
  .container-fluid.padded
    = render "navbar"
    = yield
= render "footer"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.main-content{margin-bottom:20px;}
```

this worked for me

.container-fluid.padded{:style => "margin-bottom:20px;"}

Comment: Awesome, it worked when I added that to the second line! .container-fluid.padded{:style => "margin-bottom:20px;"}